# How can I use readline synchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, readline

I'm simply trying to wait for a user to enter a password and then use it before moving on the rest of my code. The error is `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`.

```
let rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('Password: ', password => {
    rl.close();
    return decrypt(password);
}).then(data =>{
    console.log(data);
});

function decrypt( password ) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        //do stuff
        resolve(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: It looks like `rl.question` does not return promise in vanilla Node.Js (I'm assuming the question is about node.js). Actually, it returns nothing, see [source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/b869ecaacfdd218e1920f1545a88a4304efd0288/lib/readline.js#L217-L228). So I'd expect that there is no `then` method on it. So if you really need a promise, I think you'll have to implement it manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Readline's `question()` function does not return Promise or result of the arrow function. So, you cannot use `then()` with it. You could simply do

```
rl.question('Password: ', (password) => {
    rl.close();
    decrypt(password).then(data => {
       console.log(data);
    });
});
```

If you really need to build a chain with Promise, you can compose your code differently:

```
new Promise((resolve) => {
    rl.question('Password: ', (password) => {
        rl.close();
        resolve(password);
    });
}).then((password) => {
   return decrypt(password); //returns Promise
}).then((data) => {
   console.log(data); 
});
```

You probably should not forget about the `.catch()`, otherwise either solution works, the choice should be based on which code will be easier to read.

You may want to look at a couple of additional [promise usage patterns](https://www.promisejs.org/patterns/)

Comment: No, you should never use `async.js` with promises. Use the helper functions from your promise library, nothing callback-based.

Comment: @Bergi - you are right; if you have to use Promises literally, async.js is a bad idea, since it's all callbacks. I just wanted to point to certain semantics there, but maybe it's confusing rather then helpful. Myself I ended up creating couple of monadic constructs on top of Promise to deal with missing functionality in Promise/A+. I will edit the answer to point to a more helpful resource.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it was correct, and then ended up switching from readline to prompt-promise to get the desired code flow.

Answer (score 2):

And if you are scared of using callbacks and the possibility of callback hell. You can check [readline-sync package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline-sync)